# How select element in previously generated html code using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm generating a options elements for select el. And after document ready, I need do each() for all this elements. How can I do this?

ps I know how select this elements after some events, live(). But now, it's impossible.

Comment: They too big, 1.5k mixed js ;-(

Comment: Can you describe your problem in minimum codes?

Comment: Wait few minutes, I'm try on JSFiddle

Comment: I'm sorry, I just don't get what you want to do? When are you generating the options element?

Comment: Florian: After generating, I'm check data-role attr on do some magic.

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like this ?

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#id-select').find('option').each(function()
    {
        // do something with option - saved as $(this)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this script

```
$('#myselect option').each(function(){
   alert($(this).val());// option element 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gJeGK/